# Relationship between input range and channel means, standard deviations for CNNs

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, classification

So, I'm using a pretrained [PNASNet-5-Large model](https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch/blob/master/pretrainedmodels/models/pnasnet.py) to do some image classification.

In the file, it says that the input range is in [0,1] (I'm assuming pixel values of input images). The images I have are already in this range.
The channel means and standard deviation for RGB channels are stated as [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5] respectively.
Now when I use the [torchvision.transforms.Normalize](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize) to normalize the images using the stated means and standard deviations, the pixel values get to the range [-1,1].

The code I wrote for normalization:

```
transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5],[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```

I believe I'm missing something fundamental. Should I normalize the images or should I not? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Standardization of the pixel values would bring it mean close to 0 and standard deviation as 1.
2. Normalization will squeeze the values between 0 and 1.
   For RGB images, divide each channel i.e each pixel value by 255.
   For reference regarding Standardization see [here](https://medium.com/predict/standardization-on-crazy-data-python-cd5b1282a97f) and for normalization see [here](https://medium.com/@equipintelligence/normalization-of-crazy-data-python-4fa6611e7b46).